# Swift: How to decode Base64Url into json object like JWT

Tags: ios13, xcode11, jwt, swift5

I have the following JWT encode payload:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJUaXRsZSI6Ik5pY2UiLCJuYW1lIjoiSmltbXkiLCJhZ2UiOjU1fQ.DSdqRFRPM4Hep704s3cvWkpH5FFpnIc82uVUswHbaz4

But I haven't found a way to decode this string like [JWT](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJUaXRsZSI6Ik5pY2UiLCJuYW1lIjoiSmltbXkiLCJhZ2UiOjU1fQ.DSdqRFRPM4Hep704s3cvWkpH5FFpnIc82uVUswHbaz4) does.

By any chance any of you knows a way in swift to decode this payload?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Add dependencies
Add the Swift-JWT package to the dependencies within your application’s Package.swift file. Substitute "x.x.x" with the latest Swift-JWT release.

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-JWT.git", from: "x.x.x")
```

Add SwiftJWT to your target's dependencies:

```
.target(name: "example", dependencies: ["SwiftJWT"]),
```

Import package

```
import SwiftJWT
```

Cocoapods
To include Swift-JWT in a project using CocoaPods, add SwiftJWT to your Podfile:

```
pod 'SwiftJWT'
```

Try this code:

```
 let jwtEncoder = JWTEncoder(jwtSigner: jwtSigner)

 let jwtString = try jwtEncoder.encodeToString(myJWT)

 let jwtDecoder = JWTDecoder(jwtVerifier: jwtVerifier)
 let jwt = try jwtDecoder.decode(JWT<MyClaims>.self, fromString: jwtString)
```

For [documentation](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-JWT)